# What is meant by "pure" oil for Hanukka?

Tags: chanuka, beis-hamikdash, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, menorah--in-temple

The concept of "pure" oil is central to the holiday of Hanukka (see, for example,
https://www.chabad.org/holidays/chanukah/article_cdo/aid/221817/jewish/Pure-Oil.htm and
https://www.aish.com/h/c/ and https://www.ou.org/holidays/vintage-vessel/).

What makes some oil pure enough for use in the Temple to light the menorah and other oil not pure enough for this purpose?  (Surely this has been asked before, but I did not find the question when I searched a few ways.)

Clarification and update:
I relied on the English word "pure" when asking the question. But I am learning there are various Hebrew words for the word pure (e.g., relating to source of the oil, clarity, tahor), and the pasuk concerning lighting the Temple Menorah uses zach, a word that refers to physical purity rather than spiritual (tahor).  But the quote provided by @DannySchoemann seems to refer to lack of spiritual purity (i.e., tamei), so perhaps the encompassing nature of the English word pure is a useful translation, capturing all aspects of oil that would make it not suitable for use.

In any case, I found two webpages that discuss the topic of my question:
https://www.ohr.edu/this_week/talmud_tips/7148
https://www.oxfordchabad.org/templates/blog/post.asp?aid=708481&PostID=96756&p=1

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for, because what I thought you were seeking is literally the topic of the link in your question.

Comment: Your Chabad link opens "...But the Jews insisted on using only the ritually pure oil, and no other, to light the menorah in the Holy Temple, thus precipitating the renowned miracle of Chanukah.

'Ritually pure.' What, exactly, is that? What properties does a ritually pure sample of olive oil have that the others don’t?"

Comment: BTW: The tamei-tahor tag is irrelevant here, actually.

Comment: @DannySchoemann ופרצו חומות מגדלי וטמאו כל השמנים?

Comment: @JoelK - from what I see, the OP wants to know about Zach, not Tahor...

Comment: @DannySchoemann Doesn't seem that way to me, especially from the link to the chabad.org article which is explicitly discussing taharah

Comment: @JoelK - they discuss Ritually Pure - which is not the words the OP used, and is not unique to the Menora oil, which is what the OP wanted to know.

Comment: @DannySchoemann ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I guess we should wait for the OP to clarify

Comment: When most of your post is marked as a clarification because you got an answer you didn't expect, it makes the reader wish your post was put on hold originally so it could be clarified and presented in a cleaner manner.

Comment: @DoubleAA. Are you suggesting I delete this post and replace it with a cleaner one?

Comment: Not at all. Just next time someone closes your post think twice if maybe they have a point before lobbing ad hominem criticisms their way. Most of the people around here with close votes are honestly just trying to help.

Comment: @DoubleAA  When I originally posted the question, I did not have the information that I later put in an update.  How do you expect me to post information that I do not yet have?

Comment: @YehudaW I do not expect you to post information that you do not have.

Comment: @DoubleAA So how might I gone about posting this question in a manner you would see as more appropriate?

Comment: @Yehuda thought and research can to a long way. Also peer review. Remember it's not just what I see. You agree your initial post was insufficient. That's why you had to write up an entire clarification essay which is longer than the initial post. If someone says your post is not clear, then stop, think, ask for help if needed. Don't double down on problematic wordings and stubbornly complain that people are annoying you for no reason.

Comment: @DoubleAA I do not agree that my initial post was insufficient or deficient. The update was only possible based on answers and comments to my original posting.

Comment: @Yehuda that's literally the definition of insufficient and deficient. It needed more work. Closing it can let you get the help you need. You continue to double down on your initial post. It wasn't a bad post but it wasn't a perfect post. That's ok. When you can accept that, you'll be able to improve your posting skills, your experience here, and your quality of responses.

Comment: Instead you got the help you need on an open question with answers spending time on writing things that don't really answer the question, and we're left with a mess of stuff responding to obsolete stuff and posts that have layers of edits that are hard to read and follow. Overall low quality site content for the internet.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, there are two types of purity required in the oil for the Menorah: clarity of the oil, שמן זית זך, as elaborated upon in the [mishna in Menachos](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Menachot.8.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he), and ritual purity, טהרה, that is needed for all offerings in the Temple of any sort. These two concepts together contributed to the dilemma leading to the Chanuka miracle. Since the oil needed is of a very specific grade of clarity, there wasn't very much of it sitting around so that the Maccabees could just go to any old storehouse; it was only in the Temple storage areas. Those stores had been contaminated by the Greeks with ritual impurity, and only the one sealed vessel was still ritually pure. In order to attain oil that was both of the correct type and also ritually pure, they would have to travel eight days round trip, or wait until they could purify themselves through the seven day purification process and then produce new oil ([see B.Y. 680](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Beit_Yosef%2C_Orach_Chaim.670.1.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Answer (score 1):

The concept "pure oil" with regards to lighting the Menora in the Mikdash is explicitly defined in Menachot [Chapter 8 Mishnayot 4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Menachot.8.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he) & 5.

Basically, **the olives are squeezed but not crushed, producing oil that doesn't need to be filtered.

This fulfills the Biblical command of שמן זית זָך - pure olive oil - in that it was always pure and didn't need filtering to become so**.

Here's the original, with Sefaria's unedited translation. ("candlestick" meaning the menora in the Mikdash)

> ה זֵיתִים, וּבָהֶן שְׁלשָׁה שְׁלשָׁה שְׁמָנִים. הַזַּיִת הָרִאשׁוֹן, מְגַרְגְּרוֹ בְרֹאשׁ הַזַּיִת וְכוֹתֵשׁ וְנוֹתֵן לְתוֹךְ הַסַּל. רַבִּי יְהוּדָה אוֹמֵר, סְבִיבוֹת הַסַּל. זֶה רִאשׁוֹן. טָעַן בְּקוֹרָה, רַבִּי יְהוּדָה אוֹמֵר, בַּאֲבָנִים. זֶה שֵׁנִי. חָזַר וְטָחַן וְטָעַן, זֶה שְׁלִישִׁי. הָרִאשׁוֹן לַמְּנוֹרָה, וְהַשְּׁאָר לַמְּנָחוֹת. הַזַּיִת הַשֵּׁנִי מְגַרְגְּרוֹ בְרֹאשׁ הַגַּג, וְכוֹתֵשׁ וְנוֹתֵן לְתוֹךְ הַסַּל. רַבִּי יְהוּדָה אוֹמֵר, סְבִיבוֹת הַסַּל, זֶה רִאשׁוֹן. טָעַן בְּקוֹרָה, רַבִּי יְהוּדָה אוֹמֵר, בַּאֲבָנִים, זֶה שֵׁנִי. חָזַר וְטָחַן וְטָעַן, זֶה שְׁלִישִׁי. הָרִאשׁוֹן לַמְּנוֹרָה, וְהַשְּׁאָר לַמְּנָחוֹת. הַזַּיִת הַשְּׁלִישִׁי, עוֹטְנוֹ בְתוֹךְ הַבַּיִת עַד שֶׁיִּלְקֶה, וּמַעֲלֵהוּ וּמְנַגְּבוֹ בְרֹאשׁ הַגַּג, וְכוֹתֵשׁ וְנוֹתֵן לְתוֹךְ הַסַּל. רַבִּי יְהוּדָה אוֹמֵר, סְבִיבוֹת הַסַּל, זֶה רִאשׁוֹן. טָעַן בְּקוֹרָה, רַבִּי יְהוּדָה אוֹמֵר, בַּאֲבָנִים, זֶה שֵׁנִי. חָזַר וְטָחַן וְטָעַן, זֶה שְׁלִישִׁי. הָרִאשׁוֹן לַמְּנוֹרָה, וְהַשְּׁאָר לַמְּנָחוֹת:‏

> There are three [periods of gathering in the] olives and each crop gives three kinds of oil. The first crop of olives is when the olives are picked from the top of the tree; they are pounded and put into the basket. Rabbi Judah says: around the basket. This gives the first oil. They are then pressed with the beam Rabbi Judah says: with stones. This gives the second oil. They are then ground and pressed again. This gives the third oil. The first [oil] is fit for the candlestick and the others for menahot. The second crop is when the olives at roof-level are picked from the tree; they are pounded and put into the basket. Rabbi Judah says: around the basket. This gives the first oil. They are then pressed with the beam Rabbi Judah says: with stones. This gives the second oil. They are then ground and pressed again. This gives the third oil. The first [oil] is fit for the candlestick and the others for menahot. The third crop is when the last olives of the tree are packed inside the house until they become overripe; they are then taken up and dried on the roof they are pounded and put into the basket. Rabbi Judah says: around the basket. This gives the first oil. They are then pressed with the beam Rabbi Judah says: with stones. This gives the second oil. They are then ground and pressed again. This gives the third oil. The first [oil] is fit for the candlestick and the others for menahot.

Comment: Is the production process all that makes olive oil pure? Is there no concern for oil as there is for wine (yayin nesach)? Is there no concern for oil becoming tamei through some source of tuma?

Comment: @YehudaW - sure there is - that's the concept of Tahor - not connected to Zach, which is what you asked about. Zach is a physical purity, unique to the Menora Oil. Tuma is a spiritual impurity which was forbidden for anything being brought into the Temple, including the almost-clear Menora oil, the less clear oil for the Menachot, flour, water, breads, fruit, utensils, people & their clothing as well as the animals & their blood once they were slaughtered. Anything not Tahor was removed from the Temple ASAP (in such a way so as not to make the "remover" also Tameh.)